# Is it possible to use header enrichment with Facebook Messenger Platform to authenticate a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, messenger

We are a mobile operator trying to develop our messenger app on Messenger Platform to serve as a customer care channel for further business support.

One of the features we would like to add the capability for our users to check their balance, recharge and further subscription related actions. For this to work, we need to first authenticate our users using their actual subscription in the first place. As you know using social media SSO authentication is not the best solution to rely on in similar situations since the solution will be much more complex.

First thing came to our mind is to use the header enrichment feature that our network already supports. Through this feature we can easily pass the header enriched MSISDN or IMSI of a user along with his/her HTTP request to the underlying back-end server and it will always consider this user as a legit user in further communications per each request holding this enriched parameter.

Now the challenge is that in Facebook Messenger Platform, the communication is not going directly from the users messenger app to our back-end server (the webhook), instead it is going first to FB servers and then FB sends the request to our webhook, which means the header enrichment obviously won't pass and will be lost in the middle of the communications. See this diagram from the official documentation [image]

The other challenge is header enrichment only supported on HTTP request.

Can you help with a solution to this problem? A workaround maybe or other suggestions?

Appreciate your support.

Comment: You can not add just any arbitrary outside stuff into the communication flow here. If you are in control of the point where the user initiates the conversation (any of the web plugins, like Send to Messenger button or Message Us plugin), then you could pass in something that helps you identify the user via the `ref` parameter. (But that would better be a value that can not be guessed/inferred from somewhere else, because I could easily manipulate it on the client side.)

Comment: If that’s not an option, then you can only go via the PSID you get with every message. You will have to make users login to their Facebook account and get the PSID for their account at some point beforehand then.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the suggestions and your concern is valid.
I think I found a solution. Will answer my question once I verify and complete the setup.